# Problemas con mostrar elementos de base de datos en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

estoy aprendiendo Flutter y estoy realizando una aplicación web para ampliar los conocimientos, ya llevo unos días tratando de extraer info de Supabase(la base que estoy usando) y me está dando problemas con el modelado de los datos(creo que ahí está mi eror), no entiendo muy bien la parte del modelado, he leído pero creo que en la práctica se me hace mas fácil comprender.
Les agradezco la ayuda.

Este es el error que me está saliendo:
*Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'PostgrestResponse'*

Models

```
import 'package:tdi2022_charts/models/base_model.dart';

class Equipos implements BaseModel {
  @override
  String id;
  String nombre;
  String categoria;
  int jugados;
  int ganados;
  int perdidos;
  int golesfav;
  int golescontra;
  int difgoles;

  factory Equipos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Equipos(
      id: json['id'],
      nombre: json['name'],
      categoria: json['cat'],
      jugados: json['played'],
      ganados: json['won'],
      perdidos: json['lost'],
      golesfav: json['gf'],
      golescontra: json['ga'],
      difgoles: json['gd'],
    );
  }

  Equipos({
    required this.id,
    required this.nombre,
    required this.categoria,
    required this.jugados,
    required this.ganados,
    required this.perdidos,
    required this.golesfav,
    required this.golescontra,
    required this.difgoles,
  });

  Map toMap() {
    return {
      'name': nombre,
      'cat': categoria,
      'played': jugados,
      'won': ganados,
      'lost': perdidos,
      'gf': golesfav,
      'ga': golescontra,
      'gd': difgoles,
    };
  }

  @override
  String value() => nombre;
}
```

Widget

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:tdi2022_charts/models/team.dart';

class Testo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Testo> createState() => _TestoState();
}

class _TestoState extends State<Testo> {

  List<Equipos> parseEquipos(res) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(res).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Equipos>((json) => Equipos.fromJson(json));
  }

  Future<List<Equipos>> fetchEquipos() async {
    final response =
        await Supabase.instance.client.from('Equipos').select().execute();
    return parseEquipos(response);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Equipos')),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Equipos>>(
        future: fetchEquipos(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            debugPrint(snapshot.error.toString());
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return EquiposList(teams: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EquiposList extends StatelessWidget {
  const EquiposList({super.key, required this.teams});

  final List<Equipos> teams;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: teams.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(teams[index].nombre);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Parece que donde declaras final parsed (dentro de la función  parseEquipos) estas seleccionando unicamente el primer elemento con jsonDecode(res)[0]

Comment: eso se me fué, estaba haciendo pruebas con muchas maneras y se me fué eso. incluso quitandolo da el mismo error.

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías editarlo para ver como lo modificaste? Creo que en esa parte deberías generar una lista con List.from o similar para poder generar la lista de Equipos

Comment: editado, solo habia quitado el [0]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es hacer que fetchEquipos te realice la traducción del objeto. En este link veras un [ejemplo](https://dartling.dev/full-stack-with-flutter-and-supabase-pt-2-database) pero te intento indicar el cambio aproximado:

```
Future<List<Equipos>> fetchEquipos() async {
    final response =
        await Supabase.instance.client.from('Equipos').select().execute();
    final results = response.data as List<dynamic>;
    return results.map((e) => Equipos.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

PS: Lo he indicado en una sola función como ejemplo pero se puede dividir como lo tenías

Comment: Me fué de gran ayuda tus respuestas, si logré mostrar la data.

Comment: @nikos si solamente fue de ayuda dale click en el botón de flecha arriba. Si resolvió tu problema dale click en el botón de palomita. Ambos botones los hallas en la parte de la izquierda de la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Después de algunos días tratando de resolver, he encontrado mi error y comparto como encontré solucionarlo.

El error venía de mi modelo de la base de datos el archivo models.dar, no me había fijado que el id lo habia puesto int y el cambio quedó así:

```
class Equipos {
  int? id;
  String? nombre;
  String? categoria;
  int? jugados;
  int? ganados;
  int? perdidos;
  int? golesfav;
  int? golescontra;
  int? difgoles;
```